# FFmpeg: Missing filter

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

I am using `ffmpeg` installed with `Homebrew` for OS X.

An audio gate filter that I want to use, `agate` ([af_agate.c](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/af__agate_8c_source.html)) is not included with my install, but is included as a default filter in the [filter docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#agate). Perhaps development of the filter is discontinued.

Can I add the filter, and if so – how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [agate filter was added on 2015-09-22](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=ed4257de2d74ce5e5ae77ae96d58c58f1bbaeacd), so your `ffmpeg` build is probably too old. [Recompile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MacOSX) or [download a build](http://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/).

Get a build from current git master, not a release version; they are for distributors and new features are usually not backported into the point releases. 2.8 release branch was made before agate was comitted, so that is why it is not available in that release branch.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already have `ffmpeg version 2.8.2`, that should be the latest version. I have now also done `brew reinstall ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac --with-ffplay --with-freetype --with-libass --with-libquvi --with-libvorbis --with-libvpx --with-opus --with-x265`. I have also tried a complete uninstall and install. Is there some other way of getting hold of the filter?

Comment: @Winterflags Don't use a release version; they are for distributors and new features are usually not backported into the point releases. 2.8 release branch was made before agate was comitted, so that is why it is not available in that release branch. Normal users are encouraged to use a build derived from current git master. I have no experience with homebrew, but perhaps `brew info ffmpeg` will provide info on how to change the source to current git master. Or just download a build as mentioned in the answer.